# Create Single Colum Aggregat IN SSRS Matrix

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

We have a SSRS Matrix report with the following areas

RowGroup:MonthYear
ColumnGroups:Campaign,Year,Processed
Detail:Sum(Processed)

We have added a single column outside of the ColumnGroup for and expression that will show the increase/decrease of current year processed records over previous year processed records
The data is shaped like this:

lYear, MonthYear, Campaign, Processed
2014,   JUL-10,     XYZ,       120
2015,   JUL-10,     XYZ ,      60

So the formula is basically CurrentYearProcessed/PreviousYearProcessed which in this example would yield 50%

So how can we specify this when writing the expression?

Comment: IS the Sum being calculated in SSRS or in the query?

Comment: we get the sum of records received per day, per year

Comment: I guess what I mean is in SSRS you can add a column and simply put =Sum(Dataset.Value1)/Sum(Dataset.Value2)

Comment: yes but how to distinguish the 2 years is the issue

Comment: Sum(Dataset.Value1(2015 Data))/Sum(Dataset.Value2(2014 Data))

Comment: If year 2013 where 120, would process for 2014 be 100%, and 2015 still be 50%?

Answer (score 0):

Just use **IIF** to filter for the year:

```
=SUM(IIF(FIELDS!lYear.VALUE = YEAR(GETDATE()), FIELDS!Processed.VALUE, 0) / SUM(IIF(FIELDS!lYear.VALUE = YEAR(GETDATE()) - 1, FIELDS!Processed.VALUE, 0)
```

This checks your **lYear** field to see if it's the same as the current year [ YEAR(GETDATE()) ] and sums the **Processed** field. Then it divides by the previous year's SUM using similar logic.